# How to fix that "Truffle migrate" gets warnings?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I'm trying to set up a blockchain on the operating system macOS, and when I try to do the command "truffle migrate" or "truffle test" I get error messages.

I have tried changing my network id/host/port and nothing works.

````
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/CorderCurrency.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol

> compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/name/token_sale/contracts/CorderCurrency.sol:9:2: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
function CorderCurrency () public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
/Users/hanschristianmidelfart/token_sale/contracts/CorderCurrency.sol:3:1: The shadowed declaration is here:
contract CorderCurrency {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


Error: CompileError: /Users/name/token_sale/contracts/CorderCurrency.sol:9:2: SyntaxError: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.
function CorderCurrency () public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Compilation failed. See above.
at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-workflow-compile/legacy/index.js:72:1)
Truffle v5.0.32 (core: 5.0.32)
Node v10.16.3```
````

Comment: Share your smart contract code to the question

Comment: It's exactly what the error says `Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.`. Is this your constructor?